# REST Server, Delphi and Web Services - Advice needed

Tags: web-services, delphi, design-patterns, rest, delphi-xe

I am looking on advice on how best to approach a new project I need to develop.  From the outset I must add, I have 0 experience with Web development on any level.

What I need to do is provide a web interface through the browser which will communicate with a server back end.  The data retrieved will be sourced from either a DB or from another source - external device which the server itself will communicate with via IP.  The data retrieved from the external device will always be a string format of n length (non unicode) and the DB data will mostly be strings and numbers with the odd blob thrown in (storing a picture).  The communication will always go from the Client (web browser) to the Server.  I don't believe that the server would need to instigate the comms.

I have Delphi XE, so started looking at using a REST server for communication and I think that seems to be OK.  However, from what I can see, I need to create HTML web pages to "render" the data on the web browser.  Is that true?  Can I use the IW components with a REST server?  If so, I'm not sure how to get the data to/from the browser UI.  Am I better of investigating Ruby on Rails perhaps?  From what I read on a different thread in here, it's based on MVC and some other areas which I feel, design wise, would fit how I would create the application (I was planning on creating the app based on the MVP or similar design pattern).

I think REST makes the most sense, so if the IW components can't be used, are there any 3rd party products I can use which would let me design "pretty" UI html.  Given I don't know java script, would that be a stumbling block with REST too.

Thanks and hopefully I have provided enough information.

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 1):

Will a human being be responsible for typing the data retrieved from your external device into a web page?

If so, and you have no web development experience, Intraweb is definitely the way to go for Delphi programmers wanting to build a web application without learning new skills. For additional components to create a prettier UI I suggest using [TMS Software's Intraweb Component Pack Pro](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsiwpro.asp).

If you don't need a human being to manually type in this data then you don't need Intraweb at all. Instead you would write a client application which presumably interrogated your external device for the data and then transmitted it to the REST server. Look at the documentation you've used to build your REST server and it should have a section on how to build a REST client.

Comment: Yes. There will be human interaction required.  Not a lot, but all requests from the client will be effectively instantiated by the user.  eg they'll click on a button saying "Get Details" or something like that that.  

I have downloaded the TMS pack and started to have a look but not sure how - in my Reset Server Application - how I can create the HTML pages that use these components.  Although I'm guessing that I create a "TMS Intraweb" form or something but I don't get the opportunity to create those.  Same with standard Intraweb components.  Is that right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can build an ISAPI module with delphi that does the job, or include a HTTP server right into you executable with Indy, ICS or Synapse.

ISAPI will give you the freedom to choose Apache or IIS and give you all their power this way. Embeded HTTP server will give you a nice small application in which you control all ascpects of how it works.

Yes go with REST as it is simple and clean. All you need is to think and design the API (functions that your server will support). You can bind the APIs to the URL schema thus using the REST principle. I would do it simply like this.

1. A client makes a request. You show some form of GUI (load or render a HTML page with possible javascript)
2. User makes an action, you call appropriate API (or the user does it directly).
3. Show the user some result
4. Just guide the user process through a series of API calls until the result is made

You can use plain HTML and then add javascript if needed ([jquery](http://jquery.com/)) or you can use [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) from Sencha which makes building a nice GUI a lot easier and is very well structured.

I would not use any "WYSIWYG" web tools. Plain old HTML written by your favorite editor is still the king in my opinion.

Comment: Yep.  Your process is what I would look to do.  It's the step one that I'm struggling with.  In particular the "...some form of GUI...".  I might be able to muddle my way through the java script to call the rest server API.

I want to be able to imbed or add a form or something into m REST Server Application but when I go to New|Other I don't get those options with this application type.

Thanks

Comment: As I said I prefer plain HTML, but as you said, you have no experience in web design. If you have time I suggest you delve into and try to learn as much as possible. If time is an issue then yes probably Intraweb would be a good solution even though I don't like it :)

Comment: By the way simple web GUI is really easy to build. HTML is very easy to learn for basic GUI design.